# How to insert ip address in active admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I have a model called booking and I am using active admin plugin as a resource management. I have a form called booking in the backend in which I need to insert ip address and username of the currently logged in user(who insert the form data)  to the database without making any input field in backend. Please suggest. I am using mysql as database platform.

here is my controller syntax

```
class CustomizedBookingsController < ApplicationController
def create
customized_booking = CustomizedBooking.new(params[:customized_booking])
customized_booking.booked_by = current_admin_user
customized_booking.booking_ip = request.remote_ip
end
end
```

I tried lots but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Devise for authentication, you can use the method `current_user`, see the documentation here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers

To add the IP address, you have the `ip` method, part of the `ActionDispatch::Request`. Check the documentation here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-ip

So if your booking model has both `user` and `ip` fields/methods, you can set them in the `create` action in your `BookingsController`

```
def create
 booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
 booking.user = current_user
 booking.ip = request.ip
end
```